# Is there a way to serve dynamic content in a Node.js from the URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, dynamic

I'm building a basic web server as a test project, and I need to find a way to dynamically serve content based on what is in the URL. For example, lets say I typed this in the URL box: `localhost:8080/hello/world`, the resulting page would have the contents of `hello world`, because I typed that in the URL. I know in Rust with the Rocket crate I could do this:

```
#[get("/<first_term>/<second_term>)]
func terms(first_term: String, second_term: String) -> String {
    format!("{} {}", first_term, second_term);
}
```

And on the final page it would show the two terms you put in the URL. Is this possible in Node.js?

Comment: Serving content based on the URL is the only thing any web server ever does, so of course it's possible. What is your question?

Comment: @Flimzy My question is how do I do it?

Comment: So your question is how to write a web server? That's far too broad for a SO question. And there are countless tutorials online that answer it already. Use Google.

Answer (score 0):

use req.url object everything you need is stored there, also you can use request body if data is send in body to server , also you can get request paramms , using req.params ,I advice you to read documentation everything is written clear there